# What scope is needed to use the findReplace function in GoogleSheets API v4?

Tags: google-sheets-api

I want to use the findReplace request in the Google Sheets APIv4. I set up my Scope and request as defined in the Google quickstart guide for the Sheets API in Python and have confirmed that the API can talk to my spreadsheet.

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#FindReplaceRequest

```py
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
SHEET_ID = myspreadsheetid
creds = None
store = file.Storage('sheets_token.json')

if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_2_https.json', SCOPES)
        creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store, http=Http(disable_ssl_certificate_validation=True))
    with open('sheets_token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
        pickle.dump(creds, token)

adminService = build('sheets', 'v4', http=creds.authorize(Http(disable_ssl_certificate_validation=True)))

def findreplace_request(find, replacement):
  findreplace_request = {}
  findreplace_request['find'] = find
  findreplace_request['replacement'] = replacement
  findreplace_request['matchCase'] = True
  findreplace_request['matchEntireCell'] = True
  findreplace_request['searchByRegex'] = False
  findreplace_request['includeFormulas'] = False
  findreplace_request['sheetId'] = mysheetid
  allSheets = False
  request = {}
  request['findReplace'] = findreplace_request
  return request


body = {}
body.setdefault('requests',[]).append(findreplace_request('@mydate@','TODAY'))

response = adminService.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=SHEET_ID, body=my_request).execute()
```

I clearly set a scope to read and write to/from Google Sheets, but I do not understand why I get an error that says the scope is not set.

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\wnh659\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\wnh659\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 851, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1Sx0CJJo-b6Z6JUaQEQ6cJ3Yxtjv3z9BtHN9EHl0-0jU:batchUpdate?alt=json return
ed "Invalid requests[0].findReplace: scope not set.">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You want to use the findReplace request of Sheets API using python.
- You have already been able to modify Spreadsheet using Sheets API.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? I think that the reason of the error of `Invalid requests[0].findReplace: scope not set.` is that the scope for replacing the value is not defined. In your request body, the properties of `range`, `sheetId` and `allSheets` are not used. So how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

From:

```
def findreplace_request(find, replacement):
  findreplace_request = {}
  findreplace_request['find'] = find
  findreplace_request['replacement'] = replacement
  findreplace_request['matchCase'] = True
  findreplace_request['matchEntireCell'] = True
  findreplace_request['searchByRegex'] = False
  findreplace_request['includeFormulas'] = False
  sheetId = mysheetid
  allSheets = False
  request = {}
  request['findReplace'] = findreplace_request
  return request
```

To:

```
def findreplace_request(find, replacement):
  findreplace_request = {}
  findreplace_request['find'] = find
  findreplace_request['replacement'] = replacement
  findreplace_request['matchCase'] = True
  findreplace_request['matchEntireCell'] = True
  findreplace_request['searchByRegex'] = False
  findreplace_request['includeFormulas'] = False

  findreplace_request['sheetId'] = mysheetid  # Added

  allSheets = False
  request = {}
  request['findReplace'] = findreplace_request
  return request
```

- In this modification, `find` is searched from the sheet of `mysheetid`. If you want to search the value from all sheets, please use the property of `allSheets` instead of `sheetId`.

#### Note:

- If the value of property is boolean, when the property is not used, the value is used as `False` of the default value.
- In your script, I think that the following modification can be also worked.

  ```
  body = {}
  body.setdefault('requests',[]).append(findreplace_request('@mydate@','TODAY'))
  response = adminService.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=SHEET_ID, body=body).execute()
  ```

#### Reference:

- [FindReplaceRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#findreplacerequest)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: No luck with the new function :( I still get the message the scope is not set correctly. But I will update the creation of the body to get rid of the redundancy with json_dumps and loads. Thanks for that

Comment: @sironigous Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. I said about the reason of the error of ``scope is not set correctly.`` at my answer. In my environment, I could confirm that the modified script worked. Unfortunately, I couldn't replicate your issue. So can you provide your current script for completely replicating your current issue? Of course, please remove your personal information. From your current script, I would like to confirm your issue. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: @sironigous Can you cooperate to resolve your issue? I would like to resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I reran the script today without changing the scope, and i no longer received the "incorrect scope" error. I'll go ahead and mark your answer as correct.

Comment: @sironigous Thank you for replying and testing again. I'm glad your issue was resolved.